# Find all non-similar solutions of matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrix-equations

> Find all unique $($not conjugate to each other by an element of $GL_2(\mathbb{Z}))$ matrices $A \in M_2(\mathbb{Z})$, such that $A ^ 2 - 4A - I = 0$, where $I$ is the identity matrix.

From the equation it can be easily seen that matrix is a solution iff it has trace equal to $4$ and determinant equal to $-1$. The main problem is to find all conjugacy classes. Since $\mathbb{Z}$ is not a field, Jordan, Frobenius and Smith normal forms are not applicable. I also tried to brute-force the problem and solve the equation $CA = BC$, where $A$ and $B$ are two distinct solutions and $C \in GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$, but this boils down to the system of 3 diophantine equations with 4 variables, one of which is not even linear (as in [this](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1997-349-04/S0002-9947-97-01895-3/S0002-9947-97-01895-3.pdf) paper, page 3) and I have no idea how to check existence of solutions for that.
Another approach that I tried (again, without luck) was to decompose $A$ and $B$ into a product of $GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ generators and check that they differ by a cyclic permutation (as listed [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/236162), point 6) but I was not able to do that in general for this family of matrices.
I have also found a theorem (in this [presentation](https://www.msri.org/workshops/741/schedules/19379/documents/2394/assets/22918) by Svetlana Katok, slide 10), which is very cryptic to me, but I think it is impossible to use in practice.

I feel that the answer is $\pmatrix{1 & 2 \\ 2 & 3}$ and $\pmatrix{0 & 1 \\ 1 & 4}$ because I could not find any counterexamples.

Is there any simple way to find all conjugacy classes?

Comment: Smith normal form certainly applies to the integers. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, it does apply, since $\mathbb{Z}$ is a PID, but Smith Normal Form does not tell anything. For instance, $\pmatrix{0 & 1 \\ 1 & 4}$, $\pmatrix{1 & 2 \\ 2 & 3}$ and $\pmatrix{4 & 1 \\ 1 & 0}$ all have the same SNF $\pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1}$, yet the first and second matrices are not similar, but the first and the last are. If you were talking about SNF of characteristic marices, it only works for common fields.

Comment: I have removed my answer as it was incorrect; I am relinking the Conrad article here: https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/matrixconj.pdf as I think it still might be helpful. I believe the main problem with my former answer is that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$ is not the full ring of integers inside $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{5}]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your guess is correct. Here is an elementary proof. For $b\neq 0$, let

$$
F(a,b)=\begin{pmatrix} a && b \\ -\frac{a^2-4a-1}{b} && 4-a \end{pmatrix} \tag{1}
$$

Then the initial matrix $A$ is necessarily of the form $F(a,b)$ for some integers $a$ and $b$ (such that $b$ divides $a^2-4a-1$). All the conjugates of $A$ will also be of this form.

The first step is then to find, when $b$ is large enough, a suitable conjugate $F(a',b')$ of $F(a,b)$ with $|b'| \lt |b|$ ; this will allow us to argue by induction on $|b|$.

Let $t\in{\mathbb Z}$ and

$$ P=\begin{pmatrix} 1 && 1 \\ -(t+1) && -t \end{pmatrix} \in SL_2({\mathbb Z})\tag{2} $$.

Then we have (where $\ldots$ represent terms that we need not compute)

$$ 
\begin{array}{lcl}
P^{-1}AP &=& \begin{pmatrix} -t && -1 \\ \ldots && \ldots \end{pmatrix} 
        \begin{pmatrix} a && b \\ -\frac{a^2-4a-1}{b} && 4-a \end{pmatrix}
        \begin{pmatrix} 1 && 1 \\ -(t+1) && -t \end{pmatrix}  \\
        &=& \begin{pmatrix} -t && -1 \\ \ldots && \ldots \end{pmatrix} 
        \begin{pmatrix} \ldots && a-bt \\ \ldots && -\frac{a^2-4a-1}{b}+(a-4)t \end{pmatrix} \\
        &=& 
        \begin{pmatrix} \ldots && -t(a-bt)+\frac{a^2-4a-1}{b}-(a-4)t \\ \ldots && \ldots \end{pmatrix} \\
\end{array}\tag{3}$$

We have thus shown that $P^{-1}F(a,b)P$ is of the form $F(a',b')$ where

$$ 
\begin{array}{lcl}
b' &=& -t(a-bt)+\frac{a^2-4a-1}{b}-(a-4)t \\
   &=& \frac{1}{b}\bigg(-bt(a-bt)+(a^2-4a-1)-(a-4)bt\bigg) \\ 
   &=& \frac{1}{b}\bigg(-bt(a-bt)+(a^2-4a)-(a-4)bt-1\bigg) \\ 
   &=& \frac{1}{b}\bigg(-bt(a-bt)+(a-4)(a-bt)-1\bigg) \\ 
   &=& \frac{1}{b}\bigg((a-bt-4)(a-bt)-1\bigg) \\ 
   &=& \frac{1}{b}\bigg((a-bt-2)^2-5\bigg) \\ 
\end{array}\tag{4}$$

We can certainly find an integer $t$ such that $|a-2-bt|\leq \frac{|b|}{2}$, and
we then deduce from (4) that $|b'|\leq \frac{\max\bigg(5,\big|\frac{b^2}{4}-5\big|\bigg)}{|b|}$. When
$|b| \geq 7$, we have  $\max(5,\big|\frac{b^2}{4}-5\big|) \leq b^2$ and hence $|b'| \leq |b|$.

If we look a little closer, we realize that we can extend this argument : for $|b|\geq 3$ we can still find a $t$ making $|b'|\lt |b|$. Indeed, notice first that since $a^2-4a-1=0$ has no integral solutions modulo $3$, $|b|$ cannot equal $3$ or $6$. So we are left with $|b|=4$ or $5$.

When $|b|=4$, $a$ must be odd ; we can write $a=4s\pm 1$ for some integer $s$.
If $a=4s-1$, then $a-4(s-1)-2=1$ ; taking $t=sign(b)(s-1)$ therefore yields $b'=-1$ in (4).
If $a=4s+1$, then $a-4(s-1)-2=3$ ; taking $t=sign(b)(s-1)$ therefore yields $b'=1$ in (4).

When $|b|=5$, $a$ must be of the form $5s+2$ for some integer $s$, so that $a-5(s-1)-2=5$ ; taking $t=sign(b)(s-1)$ therefore yields $b'=4$ in (4).

We are now left with the case $|b|=1$ or $2$, which is the base case of the induction, and here we apply a more direct argument :

When $|b|=1$, so that $b=\varepsilon$ with $\varepsilon \in \lbrace \pm 1\rbrace$, we can write

$$
F(a,b)=Q\begin{pmatrix} 0 && 1 \\ 1 && 4 \end{pmatrix}Q^{-1}, \ \textrm{where} \ Q=\begin{pmatrix} 0 && 1 \\ \varepsilon && \varepsilon(4-a) \end{pmatrix}. \tag{5}
$$

When $|b|=2$, so that $b=2\varepsilon$ with $\varepsilon \in \lbrace \pm 1\rbrace$, we can write

$$
F(a,b)=Q\begin{pmatrix} 1 && 2 \\ 2 && 3 \end{pmatrix}Q^{-1}, \ \textrm{where} \ Q=\begin{pmatrix} 0 && 1 \\ \varepsilon && \varepsilon\frac{3-a}{2} \end{pmatrix}. \tag{6}
$$

This finishes the proof.

Comment: Thank you so much, now I understand linear algebra a lot better!

Comment: I've checked your matrices in (5) and (6) in Wolfram and they seem to produce wrong results. The ones that worked for me are $\pmatrix{\varepsilon & 0 \\ \varepsilon a & 1}$ and $\pmatrix{\varepsilon & 0 \\ \frac{\varepsilon(a-1)}{2} & 1}$ for (5) and (6) respectively.

Comment: @user971950  For my part, I've checked the matrices with PARI-GP. If you wish you can show me your Wolfram code

Comment: In (6) your matrix can't be rignt. Since $b$ is even, $a$ must be odd, but then $\varepsilon\frac{4-a}{2}$ is not an integer.

Comment: @user971950 You're absolutely right about (6), it's $\frac{3-a}{2}$ not $\frac{4-a}{2}$. It's a typo influenced by the $4-a$ in (5). Fixed now, thx.

Comment: Also, in (5) when $b = 1$, I get transposed $F(a, b)$ in WolframAlpha: "{{0, 1}, {ε, ε(4 - a)}} ^ -1 * {{0, 1}, {1, 4}}* {{0, 1}, {ε, ε(4 - a)}}, where ε = 1" - this was my query.

Comment: @user971950 You're right again, I had got the order wrong and written $Q^{-1}\ldots{Q}$ instead of $Q\ldots{Q}^{-1}$. Fixed now, thx again